# What is a Powerful Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is based on the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles, started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463).</sub>

---

If a word follows a certain rule, then I call it a Powerful Word™. If it violates this rule, then it is not a Powerful Word™.

Use the example word lists below to find the rule.

```
Powerful Word™, Not Powerful Word™
DIRECTORSHIP, INTELLECT
MONUMENTALISM, WIDTH
ACE, KING
FADE, DISAPPEAR
NONPRODUCTIVITY, ROT
GAFFE, ABERRATION
BEHELD, OBSERVED
ANNIHILATOR, BUILDER
ICEBERG, WHIRLPOOL
RELIABLE, UNSTOPPABLE
ZERO, INFINITY
PREDICATE, SUBJECT
RESEARCHER, SCIENTIST
COUNTERCULTURE, FOLK
OAK, REDWOOD
```

Each word can be tested for whether it is a Powerful Word™ without depending on other words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mekalikot has paved the way. A Powerful Word is ...

> ... a word, whose letter sum is its length raised to the power of a natural number. Usually, it's the square, but ZERO and OAK are cubes. There are words with square letters ums in the list of Non-powerful words, but these are not squares of their word length.
>
>  The letter sum is the sum of all letters, converted to their position in the alphabet: A→1, B→2, C→3, ..., Z→26. For example: ZERO → 26 + 5 + 18 + 15 = 64 = 4³.

Comment: Clever how the word length is also used.

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT]**Partially wrong**

Powerful Word™ is:

> a word that if you convert every letter to a number and get its sum, will result to the product of a Perfect Square(*the product of a rational number multiplied by itself*) or "a number, raised to the second power"

Guide:

> A=1, B=2 and so on...
>
>  1. DIRECTORSHIP = 144 = $12^2 $
>  2. MONUMENTALISM = 169 = $13^2 $
>  3. ACE = 9 = $3^2 $
>  4. FADE = 16 = $4^2 $
>  5. NONPRODUCTIVITY = 225 = $15^2 $
>  6. GAFFE = 25 = $5^2 $
>  7. BEHELD = 36 = $6^2 $
>  8. ANNIHILATOR = 121 = $11^2 $
>  9. ICEBERG = 49 = $7^2 $
>  10. RELIABLE = 64 = $8^2 $
>  11. ZERO = 64 = $8^2 $
>  12. PREDICATE = 81 = $9^2 $
>  13. RESEARCHER = 100 = $10^2 $
>  14. COUNTERCULTURE = 196 = $14^2 $
>  15. OAK = 27 = power of 3

Comment: I'm confused. Why is OAK 84? Shouldn't it be only 27? 15 + 1 + 11? 27 which is a 3 raised to 3. This will still be a `POWERFUL` word but it doesn't only apply to perfect squares.

Comment: This answer is on the right track, but incorrect. Did you check *both* lists?

Comment: oops, yeah, will edit OAK. @MikeQ, ok will check again